# How to add post with place (location) to user's wall via graph API?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

When I create a post (status update) on my own wall via facebook web site I can specify location.
How can I specify location for new post via facebook graph API?

Here is code that I use to post status updates on user's wall.

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);  
parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "message", "hi! this is my status message" }};
fbClient.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example:

```
var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(attendee.FacebookToken);
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                 {
                                     {"message", message},
                                     {"place", placeID}
                                 };
dynamic response = facebookClient.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

Comment: Is this actually working for you?  FB doesn't report an error, but right now this doesn't put the hyperlinked ' - at xxxxxxx' in the status update,  like it does if the user posts manually.  Pretty sure I'm doing it right, though I'm using the Python sdk...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a place object to set the location. This is documented on Facebook's developer docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Here is an example on doing this with the place object using the id and name of the place.

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);  
parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
    { "message", "hi! this is my status message" },
    { "place", "facebook_id_of_place" }
};
fbClient.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

Comment: Have you got this to work? The link you provided is for read access to the post. The create is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts and does not list place as a parameter. Thanks.

Comment: Well knock me over with a stick. I woke up this morning and Facebook have added this feature. It is very good too.

Comment: This example does not work. I receive the following error: FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException) (#100) {"id":"XXXXXXXXXXXX","name":"XXXXX"} does not resolve to a valid user ID.